# How to convert FlatBuffer message from binary to human readable text format with Python?

Tags: python, deep-learning, flatbuffers

I am writing a tool to dump our dedicated ML model from flatbuffers binary  into human readable text format, is there any helper like text_format for protobuf?

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted to -1, it is a perfectly reasonable question. I upvoted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no way to do that directly in Python, you'll need to invoke the command-line `flatc` tool to do so, e.g. `flatc --json myschema.fbs mybinary.bin` results in `mybinary.json`.

If necessary, it would be possible to compile the C++ json generator (and parser) into something that can be called from Python (through C), but that requires knowledge on how to create such extension libraries for Python.

Comment: Thanks Aardappel. In practice I found we need to add a `--` between shema file and binary file, it may also require a `--raw_binary` argument if there are not `file_identifier`. For those who has a similar requirment, please refer to [here](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_using_schema_compiler.html) for details.

Comment: Ah yes, forgot :)